# Converting Julian date to Java date but still cannot get Month

Tags: java, date, format, converters, julian-date

I am trying to get day ,month and year from a Julian date.

```
    String date = "13136";//Julian date
    Date convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyDDD").parse(date);
    System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

It prints

```
Thu May 16 00:00:00 BST 2013
```

which is correct.

Now I want to get Day , Month and Year from it

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(convertedDate);
  System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));


It prints 4 .
```

***It should print 5 instead of 4 . Why is it not printing as correct ? What I have done wrong here?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the javadoc of `Calendar.MONTH`:

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.

So months starts from zero so your output `4` is correct, for general usecase in your code it would be safe to add `1` to it unless you use this values as `MONTH` value in `Calendar` again.

Answer (score 0):

As the javadocs state, months begin at zero: 0 = January, 1 = February, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse ( 
    "13136", 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuDDD" ) 
).getMonthValue()
```

> 5

…for month of May 2013.

## Ordinal, not Julian

Your use of the word “Julian” is technically incorrect, though common. Folks seem to confuse day-of-year (1-365 or 1-366) with practice of counting the number of [days elapsed since January 1, 4713 BC](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php) used in some scientific fields.

The terms [“ordinal date”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date) or day-of-year are more clear.

## ISO 8601

Your format for ordinal dates is not standard. Whenever possible, use the standard [ISO 8601 formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Ordinal_dates):

- YYYY-DDD
- YYYYDDD

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Note that the formatting pattern codes in [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class are similar to the legacy class but not exactly the some.

```
String input = "13136";  //Julian date
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuDDD" );
```

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input, f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ("localDate: " + localDate );
```

> localDate: 2013-05-16

### `Month`

You can ask about the month of that `LocalDate`. The `Month` enum pre-defines a dozen objects, one for each month of the year. And unlike the crazy legacy classes, these are sanely numbered 1-12 for January-December.

If you are passing the month number around your code, I suggest you instead pass around these enum objects. Doing so gives you type-safety, valid values, and self-documenting code.

```
Month month = localDate.getMonth();
```

You can get the localized name of that month if needed.

```
String output = month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, whatever.
```

If you truly do need the number of the month 1-12, ask in either way.

```
int monthNumber = month.getValue() ;
int monthNumber = localDate.getMonthValue() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).